# Link Back to Parent Category - Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, categories, paginate-links

I´m using woocommerce and a custom post type=product and taxonomy=product_cat.
I need a link back to parent category on every single product and category pages.
Already read several posts in the web but couldn´t not make it work as I need.

I was thinking to output the function in the sidebar when necessary via a text widget plugin that accepts php. Where do I insert the function as i´m using woocomerce, and I think theme uses different templates for single product and category pages? Just in functions.php?

So, could you please help to do the function code and the html output?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're better off asking at http://community.woocommerce.com Woocommerce questions are off topic at WPDev.

Comment: Ok already asked also. But forgeting woocommerce. How can I do that for a custom post type? Could you please help?

Comment: What code for the CPTs have you tried?

Comment: For the output: <h2 class="link"><a href="<?php $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0]; echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); ?>">Return</a></h2> For the function: $cats=get_the_category();
    foreach($cats as $cat){
/*check for category having parent or not except category id=1 which is wordpress default category (Uncategorized)*/
        if($cat->category_parent == 0 && $cat->term_id != 1){
            echo '<h2 class="link"><a href="'.get_category_link($cat->term_id ).'">Return</a></h2>';
        }
        break;
    }

Comment: Also used this one with no success: function the_parent_link()
{
global $post;
if ( !$post->post_parent )
return;

echo '<a href="' . apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink($post->post_parent) ) . '">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', get_the_title($post->post_parent) ) . '</a>';
}
?> Output - <?php
the_parent_link();
?>

Comment: Please edit the question so that it isn't specifically about WooCommerce. I have provided a solution that should be independent of Woo.

Answer (score 0):

[`get_ancestors()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) seems like the function you need. If given an ID and object type, it will return an array of ancestor IDs with the first being the most distant parent/grandparent/great-grandparent/etc and the last being the immediate parent. You can use that information to construct your link.

```
function parent_id_wpse_142550($object_id,$type) {
  $anc = get_ancestors($object_id,$type); 
  $parent = array_shift($anc);
  if (!empty($parent)) {
    return $parent;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function parent_link_wpse_142550($link) {
  if (!is_wp_error($link)) {
    return '<h2 class="link"><a href="'.$link.'">Return</a></h2>'; 
  }
}

function parent_term_link_wpse_142550($object_id,$type) {
  $parent = parent_id_wpse_142550($object_id,$type);
  if(!empty($parent) && $parent != 1){ 
    $link = get_term_link($parent,$type);
    return parent_link_wpse_142550($link);
  } 
}

function parent_cpt_link_wpse_142550($object_id,$type) {
  $parent = parent_id_wpse_142550($object_id,$type);
  $link = get_page_link($parent,$type);
  return parent_link_wpse_142550($link);
}

function make_links_wpse_142550($content) {
  $links = '';
  global $post;
  $links .= parent_cpt_link_wpse_142550($post->ID,'book');

  $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'genre');

  if (!empty($terms)) {
    $term_id = array_shift($terms)->term_id;

    $links .= parent_term_link_wpse_142550($term_id,'genre');
  }

  return $links.$content;
}
add_filter('the_content','make_links_wpse_142550');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I inserted function code on functions.php and the "eco" on the sidebar text widget and nothing happens. It does not print anything... I would like to use this with a post type=product and taxonomy=product_cat. This get_ancestors function is also valid for taxonomies and custom post types right? What can be wrong here? Also I just need to write the immediate parent not all the path as "breadcrumbs".

Comment: I replaced the original code with code a bit more complicated and flexible. I think it should work with any _taxonomy_. `get_ancestors()` should work with a CPT but not the function used to generate the link. You could use this as a model for a sibling function to create links for CPTs.

Comment: Hi, thanks again. It works only for the declared "echo category ID". What I need is that in all the pages the function recognize in which cpt category i am and echo the immediate parent link. Like Breadcrumbs work, but without the all path.

Comment: Yes, the function makes no effort to detect what page you are on or to guess what taxonomy you need. You need to do that and pass the information to the function. The last line is sample usage, that's all.

Comment: Humm, ok I understand but i think I cannot do it by myself. I need to know the cpt/taxonomy and the category ID I´m in. Should get in them already inside the function code or when writing the "echo"?

Comment: Tried this as output but it doesn´t work:<?php echo parent_term_link_wpse_142550(<?php echo get_post($post_id)?>,'<?php echo get_post_type( $post )?>'); ?>

Comment: ^^ That PHP syntax is badly wrong and you are trying to use that with a CPT. I told you that it should work with a _taxonomy_ and that you'd need to write a similar function for a CPT.

Comment: Tried this one also no success:<?php echo parent_term_link_wpse_142550 (get_term_by('id'),'product_cat'); ?> Could you give a help on the correct sentence, cuz i don´t know almost nothing about php?

Comment: Last edit. Now you have a set of functions and some other sample code. You _need to figure it out from here_.

Comment: Correcting this php sentence is nothing for you. Maybe 3 secs. I cannot believe in what you said, neither understand the benefict or propose of your answer. I need to figure it out??? If I knew how to figure it out I was not here asking for HELP. Where I live is now 2am in the morning and I´ve already tried dozens of different ways, read many post about it and asked for help on different sites since yesterday. Maybe you are a lil tired. Very Thankful!!!